# Error in program to automatically name PDFs

Tags: python

I made a small program to read a regex in a PDF and name it accordingly. I searched through the archives and pieced this together from several different sources and questions.

The hope is that I can have a monitored folder, and immediately when an invoice pdf is created, the handler will kick on and rename it.

My result works, though sometimes it seems to crash or stick or throws an error, or simply does not rename the PDF without any mention of error.

I have tried eliminating the loop in the convert_pdf_to_text function, but could not get it to work without it.

I am an R person, and writing scripts in Python is not my strong suit!

Thanks for any suggestions to make it a bit more robust.

I have also attached the error that I got. [python_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQLD2.png)

Another error I got here- [python_error_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyql.png)

```
import sys, time, logging, io, re, os

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,
                                  password=password,
                                  caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    inv_num = re.findall("(\d{5})", text)[1]
    inv_name = text.split('\n', 1)[0]
    new_name = inv_num + " " + inv_name

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return new_name

def renameFileToPDFTitle(path, fileName):
    fullName = os.path.join(path, fileName)
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fileName)

    newName = convert_pdf_to_txt(fullName)  + extension
    newFullName = os.path.join(path, newName) 
    os.rename(fullName, newFullName)

class Event(LoggingEventHandler):
    def dispatch(self, event):
        for fileName in os.listdir(path):
        # Rename only pdf files
            fullName = os.path.join(path, fileName)
            if (not os.path.isfile(fullName) or fileName[-4:] != '.pdf'):
                continue
            renameFileToPDFTitle(path, fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = Event()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```